# Understanding Prolog's side effects e.g. write/1

Tags: prolog

I'm currently learning Prolog and I have a hard time understanding side effects.

I had an excercise to write a predicate that writes some string N-times. The given solution looks like this:

```
n_times(N) :- 1 =< N.
n_times(N) :- N > 1, N1 is N - 1, n_times(N1).
test_x(N) :- n_times(N), write('x'), fail.
test_x(_).
```

Can somebody explain why this works? Why is `write('x')` executed N times? As far as I understand Prolog it should try to find a solution for `n_times(N)` and then execute `write('x')` once. I suppose this has something to do with side effects but I could not find a practical explanation for that.

My own solution looks like this by the way:

```
test_x(N) :- write('x'), N1 is N - 1, N1 >= 1, test_x(N1).
```

Here I can see that `write` gets called on each recursive call.

Comment: What is `ue_tab/1` doing here? Shouldn't this be `test_x/1`?

Comment: You are correct. My mistake.

Comment: " ***Prolog it should try to find a solution for n_times(N) and then execute write('x') once***" well not exactly, for each choice point-solution of n_times write gets executed...

Comment: the first clause should be `n_times(N) :- N =< 1.` ------ `test_x(N) :- ..., fail.` is a *failure-driven loop* (in case you didn't know).

Comment: You just need to understand basic Prolog behavior. When you have a sequence of calls separated  by commas, if any one of them fails, then Prolog *backtracks* to look for more solutions to prior calls and, if successful, moves forward again. Thus `n_times(N), write('x'), fail.` will do `write('x')` for every time `n_times(N)` succeeds because `fail` always backtracks, `write('x')` doesn't re-execute on backtracking, and `n_times(N)` will succeed again (until all solutions are found).

Comment: I think I get it now. So for every `N >= 1`, Prolog succeeds with the first clause, fails and then backtracks to the second clause which calls first clause with `N - 1`. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a so called *failure-driven loop*.

A simpler situation to get to terms with is

```erlang
repeat :- true.
repeat :- repeat.

forever_x :- repeat, write('x'), fail.
```

which *forever* prints `x` at the prompt.

Why? Because Prolog's conjunctions (`,`, "and") of goals are just like *nested loops*:

```erlang
find(G):- this(X1), that(X2).
```

is just like (in *pseudocode*)

```erlang
def find(G):
         foreach solution X1 to { this(X1) }:
             foreach solution X2 to { that(X2) }:
                 yield G using the found values X1, X2.
```

***Backtracking occurs naturally in loops.*** If for some `X1` there is no `X2` that satisfies `that(X2)`, no `G` is yielded, and the outer loop just skips to the next value of `X1` that satisfies `this(X1)`.

And Prolog's disjunctions (`;`, "or") of goals are just *juxtapositions of loops* (just putting one loop after another).

Thus, the definition of `repeat` acts as if defined by

```erlang
def repeat:
     yield        % yield an empty value that isn't used anywhere
     repeat       % call self, yielding again; and again; repeating endlessly

def forever_x:
     foreach solution to { repeat }:           % endless stream of empty solutions
         foreach solution to { write('x') }:   % there will be only one, empty solution
            foreach solution to { fail }:      % there will be no solutions, ever, so
                yield                          % this will never happen
```

and your `n_times/1`, as if

```erlang
% n_times(N) :- N =< 1.
% n_times(N) :- N > 1, N1 is N - 1, n_times(N1).

def n_times(n):
    foreach solution to { n =< 1 }:            % succeeds at most once
         yield n
    foreach solution to { n > 1 }:             % at most once, mutually exclusively
         foreach solution to { n1 = n - 1 }:   % there will be only one solution
             n_times(n1)
```

so naturally this will succeed, i.e. "yield", *n* times.